# Automatically closing nav bar with UI Bootstrap on selection or page change

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using UI Bootstrap, and want to close the nav bar when a user selects an item from the dropdown or clicks a link elsewhere on the page.

When I use the following code, the only way to close the nav bar is to click the nav bar button again.

Any suggestions on how to get this working? I've seen examples on SO that use directives, but I assumed there was a more straightforward way to accomplish this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl as nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" class="navbar-toggle" >
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div collapse="isCollapsed" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
        <li><a ui-sref='contact'>Contact</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref='about'>About</a></li>         
        <li><a ui-sref="selection">Services</a></li>
     </ul>  
   </div>
 </div>  
</nav>

.controller('DropdownCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.status = {
      isopen: true
  };
  $scope.toggled = function(open) {
};

  $scope.toggleDropdown = function($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();
      $event.stopPropagation();
      $scope.status.isopen = !$scope.status.isopen;
     };
  }]);
```

Comment: sorry but I'm not sure what you are trying to acheive here ?? could you please make a plunker ? and you are missing 2 closing </div> tags!

Comment: @macrog when the collapsed navbar is opened, the only way to close it again is by clicking on the navbar button. I'd like it to also close when a user selects a menu item (e.g., clicks on "Contact") or when the user navigates to a new page. Currently, the dropdown stays open even when navigating to a new page.

Comment: is my solution working for you ?

Comment: @macrog Thank you for the answer. I was hoping to find a solution that closes the navbar any time someone navigates to a new page (e.g., if one clicks the home link or hits the back button).

Answer (score 1):

First ! Is there a reason why you are creatin 2 controllers for one nav bar ?

replace:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl as nav">
```

with

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
```

To close when a user selects a menu item (e.g., clicks on "contact / about / services")

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a ui-sref='contact' ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref='about' ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">About</a></li>         
    <li><a ui-sref="selection" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Services</a></li>
</ul>
```

hope it helps.

You can check my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IS1xqgUNqY1YxEP9GIjB?p=preview), just take note that I added you navbar to my existing plunker, so it have other thing on it.